# Can Proptypes Number in React take Float?

Tags: reactjs, properties

Can optionalNumber be a floating point number in this case?

```
      optionalNumber: React.PropTypes.number
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[React.PropTypes.number](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L228) is performing a `typeof` check against `'number'` so any number (`1`, `.1`, `1e-3`, `Infinity`, `NaN`) will pass.

Comment: A bit ironic that `NaN` passes as a number :)

Comment: `NaN` is a dishonest number

Comment: The "React.PropTypes.number " link is not longer working